# Controlling Access To Amazon S3 buckets

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have a requirement where users are part of groups..user1 is part of group1, user2 is part of group2, user3 is part of group1 and group2..etc..

each group has static content which i want to host in Amazon S3. So far in my research, i concluded that i will need to create a bucket for each group.

My question is:

How do i control access to users ?

user1 should only be able to access resources of bucket belonging to group1.(upload, download etc.)

users should not be able to access resources of groups they are not part of.

I imagine this is a typical scenario, but so far my google-fu is not yeilding any fruitful results.

I have a NodeJS/Express REST API as my middle tier. Please advise me on how to engineer for this requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a bucket per group. You could create one bucket, then in each bucket create a directory for each group and grant access only to the corresponding group. You can use [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/iam/) to create the groups and users. Refer to [this AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html) for a walkthrough on this scenario.

If you need to scale to many users and groups, you should look at the [AWS Security Token Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/Welcome.html) which scales to millions of users and doesn't require IAM credentials at all. Your application is responsible for authenticating users and managing their accounts and group membership, but the token service can allow access to AWS resources including S3.

Comment: This doesn't look like it is meant to scale in a web application. My app can have potentially 100's if not 1000's of users and groups.

Comment: You didn't mention that this was for an app. Added a reference to Security Token Service in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is a web application. 'GetFederationToken' matches what i had in mind. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingFedTokens.html